# Rails 5 named scope with polymorphic, UndefinedColumn

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to write a named scope in my model that retrieves all instances that are associated with another model. This is the model where I need the scope to retrieve all instances with `EmailTemplate`

```
class Answer < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :email_template, as: :templateable
  validates :text, presence: true

  scope :with_template, -> { where.not(email_template: nil) }
end
```

And my other model

```
class EmailTemplate < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :templateable, polymorphic: true
  validates :pre, presence: true
  validates :post, presence: true
end
```

When I do `Answer.with_template`, this error shows up.

```
[3] pry(main)> Answer.with_template
   (6.6ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "answers" WHERE ("answers"."templateable" IS NOT NULL)
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  no existe la columna answers.templateable
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "answers" WHERE ("answers"."templateabl...
                                              ^
: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "answers" WHERE ("answers"."templateable" IS NOT NULL)
from /home/pedro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:620:in `async_exec'
```

Tried with this too, and doesn't work:

```
scope :with_template, -> { where.not(templateable: nil) }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  no existe
>   la columna answers.templateable

As per the *polymorphic associations*, the `EmailTemplate` should be having the `templateable_id` not the `Answer`. So you should *join the models* and query them

This should work

```
scope :with_template, -> { includes(:email_template).where.not("email_templates.templateable_id IS NULL") }
```

Comment: Could you tell me the difference between that and what I've posted in my own answer?

Comment: @PedroAdameVergara The *where*

Comment: Sorry, then I don't fully understand why mine works as expected and I should be using your solution. Can you explain it?

Comment: @PedroAdameVergara The difference the where make sure that there is no `email_templates` with `templateable_id` as `null`. You can check the *SQL* generated with it by appending `explain` in the end like `Answer.with_template.explain`

Comment: Oh, OK! Sorry. I updated the question as it was wrong. I want the records WITH association. That's why my solution works, and the question was looking for not associated records. Sorry for the mispelling, my head was away yesterday.

Comment: @PedroAdameVergara Did you check my solution? Its same as your answer. I mean it will get you the records with association and the extra thing is it will make sure not to include without association records

Comment: Yes, I checked it. Just updated the question for bad redacting. I noticed that appending `explain` to your solution crashes, but changing `includes` to `joins` works as espected with explain. And now I fully understood you. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I just found the solution. Noticed that `where` works with own attributes.

```
scope :with_template, -> { joins(:email_template) }
```